# Function alias for function with default argument

Tags: c++

I want to use a alias for a function with a default argument:

```
class Foo
{
  static void bar(int i, int j=0);
};

const auto aliasFunction = Foo::bar;
```

However when I try to call this by calling `aliasFunction(1)` the compiler complains that the function takes two arguments. Is there an easy fix for this?

Comment: Good old `#define` maybe? (but only for the name)

Comment: If you use a lambda with a default argument, you get the option (and the debt!) to (re-)define the default argument. Is having a default argument for the “alias” really *that* useful?

Answer (score 3):

You can use either a [lambda](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda) to do this:

```
auto aliasFunction = [](int i)
{
    return Foo::bar(i);
};
```

Or using [`std::bind`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind) (which kind of deprecated in favor of lambdas):

```
using namespace std::placeholders;  // For _1
auto aliasFunction = std::bind(&Foo::bar, _1, 0);
```

However it's not possible to create a true alias of a function (your definition doesn't create an alias either. but a pointer).

---

For completeness, but not recommended, it's of course possible to use the preprocessor and create a macro:

```
#define aliasFunction(i) Foo::bar(i)
```

Comment: AFAIK, parameterizes macros do not allow default arguments, is it possible for lambdas?

Comment: @Wolf Lambda arguments are just like any other function argument, so it can have default arguments (`[](int i, int j = 0) { ... }` is valid).

Comment: For reference, see [*Default arguments*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_arguments), meanwhile I doubt the value of handling another default value for that purpose.